# Не работает сессия в Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Всем привет. Возникла такая проблема, я переадресовываю (через routes.php) класс на центральную страницу (вместо www.site.ru/class получается www.site.ru), но на ней не работает сессия (метод авторизации в классе, если быть точным), а на www.site.ru/class - все работает отлично. В чем проблема?

Comment: Где у вас сессия работает? в каком методе класса?

Comment: Проверьте путь у куки.

Comment: Используйте profiler для отладки.